# Ref not working on custom component in Vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, ref, custom-component, quasar

I'm using Vue3 with the composition API. In a form-component I put ref's on each field (child-component).

For some reason the `ref`'s of the custom components are different from `ref`'s for Quasar components.

When I `console.log` a `ref` to a custom component I get this in DevTools:

```
Proxy {__v_skip: true}
```

(without any properties in Target)

while a ref to a Quasar components gives this :

```
Proxy {…}
```

(with all properties of the component in Target)

For this reason I can't use the `ref` to access properties or methods of these child components.

I have no idea what `__v_skip` even means.
My custom components are defined with `script setup`, could that be a reason?

Any idea how to fix this?

**UPDATE**
If I use `defineExpose` in the child components for the properties and methods I want to access from outside with a `ref`, it does work. Not really handy though, since these components have *lots* of props.

Comment: You're addressing the wrong thing. If you have a problem consider explaining it and providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for it. You shouldn't pay attention to internal Vue properties. There's a possibility that different representation of refs indicates that something wrong was done with them, but there are not enough reasons to consider this.

Answer (score 12):

Seem likes currently you **cannot** access the custom component by ref, if your component is written by Composition API (`<script setup>`). But you can try the way I mention underneath.

In the Vue 3 doc, there are some lines mentioned this behavior:

> An exception here is that components using `<script setup>` are **private**
> **by default**: a parent component referencing a child component using
> `<script setup>` won't be able to access anything unless the child
> component chooses to expose a public interface using the `defineExpose`
> macro

Read more here: [Vue 3 - Ref on Component](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#ref-on-component)

That means if you want to access anything from the custom component, your component has to expose that information. I think it's because in Vue 3 you don't need to have root component anymore, so if  you define a ref, Vue does not know what the component you want to ref to.

### But...

You can try to use `yourRef.value.$el`, maybe it will help.

**Example:**

```js
// Parent.vue
<template>
  <Child ref="childRef">
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
// Import things...

const childRef = ref<InstanceType<typeof Child> | null>(null);

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(childRef.value.$el); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Only the original vue defineExpose method works